# React Native Expo: How to see Axios error full message?

Tags: typescript, react-native, mobile, axios, expo

I'm using Axios with React Native and I'm getting a network error.

On React JS(Web) when I used to console log the error or response I would get all the details but when I log the error on Expo I only see "Axios error: Network error". So how to see the full response like React web?

I searched around the web for solution but I couldn't find anything relevant.

Comment: What does your code look like? Please [edit] your question. Have you checked out the Axios [Handling Errors documentation](https://axios-http.com/docs/handling_errors)?

Answer (score 1):

The Axios Error object can be serialised as JSON for better observability using its `toJSON()` method.

Unfortunately, this omits any actual response data which can contain very useful information. What I like to use is a combination of both. For example

```ts
try {
  const res = await axios({ /* ... */ });
} catch (err) {
  // Typescript type guard for AxiosError
  if (axios.isAxiosError(err)) {
    console.error("Axios request failed", err.response?.data, err.toJSON());
  } else {
    console.error(err);
  }

  throw new Error("Request failed");
}
```

For more information, see [Handling Errors](https://axios-http.com/docs/handling_errors)